# How to run composer to download google_chart library?

Tags: composer, theming

Hi I am trying to install [charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module with its Google_charts library, and I am following the [Getting started](https://www.drupal.org/node/2423033) document for installation. 
I am stuck in the step of running composer to download and install Google chart library. How is this done? How do I run composer in Drupal?

Please help, thanks

Comment: Composer is run from the command line, not from within the Drupal UI. At least not yet. https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Comment: @Kevin, thanks for the reply. what command should I run to install the libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this to install on your current project:

```
composer require gufy/google-charts:dev-master;
```

Or you can add this package to your *composer.json* file:

```
"require": {
    "gufy/google-charts": "dev-master"
}
```

Then use composer to install this package:

```
composer update
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the answer. I added require lines inside composer.json file in my project. But when I run "composer update"; I get composer: command not found error.

Comment: I tried setting PATH for composer, but I have only composer.lock and composer.json files in my project. I dont have composer.phar file.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer posted by @Mohammad_AlQanneh is the right answer, in addition to that, composer.phar file was missing in my project, and so I had to install, create an alias and then followed @Mohammad_AlQanneh's instructions and it worked.

To install:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer'
```